# Auto Sweep/Scroll Carousel in KivyMD (Python)

Tags: python, scroll, kivy, carousel, kivymd

I want to make a 2 Slide Carousel with auto scrolling in `KivyMD` with `Python`. On Startup, the App starts from the The first Slide of Carousel and it should be changed to 2nd slide after 3 seconds.

### Here is my Code

**.kv**

```
<WelcomeScreen>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color : 1, 1, 1, 1
    Carousel:
        id: caraousel
        on_current_slide: app.current_slide(self.index)
        MDFloatLayout:
            Image:
                source: "Assets/1.png"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                size_hint: .3, .3

            MDLabel:
                text: "Slide 1"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .087}
                halign: "center"
                font_name: "Poppins-Light"
                font_size: "14sp"
                color: rgba(135, 143, 158, 200)
        MDFloatLayout:
            Image:
                source: "Assets/2.jpg"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                size_hint: .8, .8
            MDLabel:
                text: "Slide 2"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .47}
                halign: "center"
                font_name: "Poppins-Regular"
                font_size: "25px"
                color: rgba(1, 3, 23, 225)
```

**.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.utils import rgba
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (310, 580)

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AppApp (MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('app.kv')

    def current_slide(self, index):
        pass

AppApp().run()
```

Anyone can help me with this Issue? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try using `Clock` ?

Comment: No. I have no Idea. Can you Please Show a little code Example that suits to my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `Clock.schedule_interval` to perform automatic loading of sliders. Trigger that action from anywhere in your code, for example to make it happen from the very beginning, trigger it from the method `on_start` of class app as,

**app.kv** file.

```py
<WelcomeScreen>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color : 1, 1, 1, 1
    Carousel:
        id: caraousel
        on_current_slide: app.current_slide(self.index)
        MDFloatLayout:
            Image:
                source: "Assets/1.png"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                size_hint: .3, .3

            MDLabel:
                text: "Slide 1"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .087}
                halign: "center"
#                font_name: "Poppins-Light"
                font_size: "14sp"
                color: rgba(135, 143, 158, 200)
        MDFloatLayout:
            Image:
                source: "Assets/2.jpg"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                size_hint: .8, .8
            MDLabel:
                text: "Slide 2"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .47}
                halign: "center"
#                font_name: "Poppins-Regular"
                font_size: "25px"
                color: rgba(1, 3, 23, 225)
```

**main.py** file.

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.utils import rgba
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (310, 580)

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AppApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('app.kv')
        return WelcomeScreen()

    def on_start(self):
        # Access the carousel.
        carousel = self.root.ids.caraousel
        # Set infinite looping (optional).
        carousel.loop = True
        # Schedule after every 3 seconds.
        Clock.schedule_interval(carousel.load_next, 3.0)


    def current_slide(self, index):
        pass

AppApp().run()
```

---

### Update:

Try avoiding the App's instance name as `AppApp` and related .kv file as `app.kv` simultaneously, that might cause problems during auto .kv loading. However loading the file explicitly and then returning the root from method `build` (or declaring in `.kv` file) should work.

Comment: Oh... An Error Appeared! `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'carousel'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Kusal\Python\Projects\venv\Projects\Diary\Diary.py", line 5
................

File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
`
What to Do Now?

Comment: That did exactly what it supposed to do at my end (with NO error). Make sure you didn't change the spelling (as it seems your original id was with 'caraousel', but in error message with 'carousel').

Comment: I edited it to correct the spelling. and in the current script it has changed as `carousel` in both files. But the error still happens....No any other way?

Comment: Not sure what really makes such error without seeing the modified code. However try changing the names of your `.kv` file, App's class etc.

Comment: Can you please provide your full code with `.kv` file if you can? It will be a great help. Thanks